# Android Facebook SDK Login onCompleted method not called

Tags: android-facebook

I'm trying to get the simple login activity to work as described on the Facebook developers page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

My code so far:

```
package com.xxxx.android;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class MyTestsActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button mFbLogin;
    private TextView mWelcome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_tests);
        setViews();

      }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bFbLogin:
            facebookLogin();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    mWelcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
    }

    private void setViews() {
        mFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFbLogin);
            mFbLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        mWelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcome);
    }

}
```

The app loads, I press the login button, it opens a diaglog prompting me to allow access to the app, after I press yes, the activity goes back to how it was. The textview does not update with the user information that should happen in the onCompleted method that facebook has given. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I saw your code dude. I am not a mature developer of Facebook SDK for android but i think the problem is in onActivityResult. Try to implement the following code.. I also implemented the same code as your doing but my problem was resolved.

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```